# Resource shrinker in safe mode doesn't behave approperly

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-proguard

I am currently learning about resource shrinking according to the [android user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#strict-reference-checks) and i'm stuck with wrong behavior of given example:

```
String name = String.format("img_%1d", angle + 1);
res = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

If i get it right it is supposed to leave every drawable with name starting with img_ but i have made my own test that looks like this:

```
int postfix = 1;
String name2 = String.format("img_%1d", postfix);
int imageResId = getResources().getIdentifier(name2, "drawable", getPackageName());

imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imageResId));
```

and i also have put some img_ starting drawables into drawables package

[image: Screen shoot of project tree]

In gradle i have

```
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

The final result of working app should look like this:

[image: Working app after keeping drawable]

but if i don't set tools:keep="@drawable/img_1" in my keep.xml, then i end up with this:

[image: Bad behavior]

And i get that effect regardless i make keep.xml to be safe (altho it should be safe by default) or delete keep.xml. I also get in my resoutces.txt:

```
Skipped unused resource res/drawable/img_1.png: 2140 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
```

Can anybody tell my why is this not working... safe? Am I doing something wrong here, or it's not working the way it's supposed to work?